# WordPress Custom Post Type and Custom Template

Tags: wordpress

I have created my custom Post type on WordPress 3.5.1

So under Dashboard I see my custom Post type on the left hand side.   So, I did a Add New under this Custom Type.

But I don't see any Template page I can choose for this Custom Type.

I create a file called archive-customtype.php  that's a template page and put into my theme folder.

On the older WordPress to change different template you do a

From the Page Attributes meta box select Template > Custom Type and publish the page.

So my question, on this new 3.5.1 where do I select the template for this custom post type?
Right now it's using the default one.

Comment: Templates are for Pages, not for Post ..http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates

Answer (score 1):

Install the Custom post types plugin by iLocalize http://wordpress.org/plugins/types/. They have a lot of tutorials on how to add the custom posts to a page. This tutorial http://youtu.be/1SXyHbgjYaI here is the best I've found but there are more the wp-types website. Look up how to create a new page template on wordpress . org and place the code from the tutorial to the page template. Hope this helps.